# Copy NAV Database Structure to another Database along with Data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, navision

I need to Copy a Company in NAV Database to another Company in Different Database with SQL Query. I have achived this using the code below, but if the Structure is different in the Source or Destination my code fails. Please help me in modifying it, so i can copy the Structure and Data from the Source and replace Data and Structure in the Destination.
The code is given below.

```
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:        Prajeesh 
    -- Create date:   31.03.2015
    -- Description:    Function for copying comany from one database to another
    -- =============================================
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_NAVCopyCompany_v2] 
        @sourcecompany varchar(max), 
        @targetdb varchar(max),
        @targetcompany varchar(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        declare @tablename varchar(1000)
        declare @columns varchar(max)
        declare @columnname varchar (max)
        declare @targettable varchar (max)
        declare @isidentity int
        declare @sqlcommand nvarchar (max) = 'select name from '+@targetdb+'.sys.all_objects where type=''U'' and object_id>0 and name like '''+@sourcecompany+'$%'''
        declare @sqlcommandIdentity nvarchar (max)
        declare @tablevar table(name varchar(300))
        declare @columntablevar table(COLUMN_NAME varchar(300))
        declare @identitytablevar table(C int)
        insert into @tablevar(name) exec sp_executesql  @sqlcommand
        DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR for
          select name from @tablevar
        OPEN table_cursor

        FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor 
        INTO @tablename
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            --RAISERROR (@tablename, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT 
               set @sqlcommand = 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM '+@targetdb+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '''+@tablename+''' and COLUMN_NAME <> ''timestamp'''
            DELETE from @columntablevar
            insert into @columntablevar(COLUMN_NAME) exec sp_executesql  @sqlcommand
            DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR for select COLUMN_NAME from @columntablevar

            select @columns=''
            OPEN column_cursor
            FETCH NEXT from column_cursor
            INTO @columnname
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @columns=@columns+',['+@columnname+']'
                FETCH NEXT from column_cursor
                INTO @columnname
            END
            CLOSE column_cursor;
            DEALLOCATE column_cursor;
            select @columns = SUBSTRING(@columns,2,LEN(@columns)-1)
            --RAISERROR (@columns, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT 
            select @targettable= @targetdb+'.dbo.['+@targetcompany+SUBSTRING(@tablename,LEN(@sourcecompany)+1,LEN(@tablename)-LEN(@sourcecompany)+1)+']'
            --
            select @isidentity=COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =@tablename AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
            --
            set @sqlcommandIdentity = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM '+@targetdb+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME ='''+@tablename+''' AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, ''IsIdentity'') = 1'
            DELETE from @identitytablevar
            insert into @identitytablevar(C) exec sp_executesql  @sqlcommandIdentity
            select @isidentity=SUM(C) FROM @identitytablevar

            RAISERROR (@targettable, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT 
            set @sqlcommand = ''
            IF (@isidentity>0)
              set @sqlcommand = @sqlcommand + 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+@targettable+' ON;'

            set @sqlcommand = @sqlcommand + 'delete from '+@targettable+';'
            set @sqlcommand = @sqlcommand + 'insert into '+@targettable+ ' ('+ @columns + ')'
            + '    select '+@columns
            + '       from ['+@tablename+']' 

            IF (@isidentity>0)
              set @sqlcommand = @sqlcommand + ';SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+@targettable+' OFF'
            --RAISERROR (@sqlcommand, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT 
            exec sp_executesql @sqlcommand
            FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor 
            INTO @tablename
        END 
        CLOSE table_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
    END
```

The Query is called as

```
use SourceDatabase
exec sp_NAVCopyCompany_v2 'Source Company_','Destination Database','Destination Company'
```

Comment: Which version of Navision are you using? Are you trying to insert a company into another Navision database or are you trying to restore a Navision database using SQL?

Comment: I am using Nav 2013 R2 . i am using SQL query to copy NAV database to another Database, because it need to be automated and the Company name and user setting's need to be different. Its done outside NAV.

Comment: Have you tried using built-in functionality? It has the ability to export the company and application structure. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn789595(v=nav.80).aspx - the help is for NAV 2015, but this functionality has been introduced to NAV 2013 R2 since CU8.

Comment: Thanks Sergeyol, the Data copy functionality also fail in this case since the Test Database can be modifyed in Structure and can't automate this.